# Missing outer border of a flextable in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, flextable, officer, officedown

I have an issue I can't resolve. There may be something missing in the flextable package, but I may be wrong. Please, see the example.
This is my tabular data:

```
structure(list(groupName = c("Group A", "Group A", "Group A", 
"Group A", "Group A", "Group B", "Group B", "Group B", "Group B", 
"Group B"), ID = c("14243", "14363", "14373", "14934", "14980", 
"14400", "14488", "14513", "14549", "15407"), `Day -15` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 174, 143, NA, NA, NA, NA, 169), `Day -13` = c(NA, NA, 
NA, 164, 132, NA, NA, NA, NA, 178), `Day -12` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), `Day -11` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 189, NA, 213, NA, NA, 
204), `Day -10` = c(NA, NA, NA, 187, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    `Day -9` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 178, NA, 204, 227, 257, 232), 
    `Day -8` = c(NA, NA, NA, 286, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Day -7` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 258, 311, 291, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I build a flextable like this:

```
flx <- flextable(tbl2) %>% 
  border_outer() %>% 
  add_header_row(values = c(
    "groupName",
    "ID",
    rep("measurement", ncol(tbl2) - 2)
  )) %>% 
  merge_h(part = "header") %>% 
  merge_v(part = "header") %>% 
  valign(valign = "bottom", part = "header") %>% 
  align(align = "center", part = "all")
```

and the output is [image]
As You can see there is missing border in the first row of the header.
I tried to add `border_outer()` once again, but no effect. I also tried `vline_right` function, but no effect too. The only thing I found was to add this step:

```
flx %>% border_inner_v(part = "header")
```

but it adds border to every cell in the header which is not what I need. [image]

I think the step `merge_h` in my pipeline is the place where bad things happen. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a special case, the border you are seeing on the right side is actually the right border of the third cell that has been merged with all following cells.

```r
library(flextable)
library(magrittr)

tbl2 <- structure(list(groupName = c("Group A", "Group A", "Group A", 
"Group A", "Group A", "Group B", "Group B", "Group B", "Group B", 
"Group B"), ID = c("14243", "14363", "14373", "14934", "14980", 
"14400", "14488", "14513", "14549", "15407"), `Day -15` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 174, 143, NA, NA, NA, NA, 169), `Day -13` = c(NA, NA, 
NA, 164, 132, NA, NA, NA, NA, 178), `Day -12` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), `Day -11` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 189, NA, 213, NA, NA, 
204), `Day -10` = c(NA, NA, NA, 187, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
`Day -9` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 178, NA, 204, 227, 257, 232), 
`Day -8` = c(NA, NA, NA, 286, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Day -7` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 258, 311, 291, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), 
class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# solution 1
flextable(tbl2) %>% 
  border_outer() %>% 
  add_header_row(values = c(
    "groupName",
    "ID",
    rep("measurement", ncol(tbl2) - 2)
  )) %>% 
  merge_h(part = "header") %>% 
  merge_v(part = "header") %>% 
  valign(valign = "bottom", part = "header") %>% 
  align(align = "center", part = "all") %>% 
  vline(i = 1, j = 3, border = fp_border_default(), part = "header")

# solution 2
flextable(tbl2) %>% 
  border_outer() %>% 
  add_header_row(values = c(
    "groupName",
    "ID",
    rep("measurement", ncol(tbl2) - 2)
  )) %>% 
  merge_h(part = "header") %>% 
  merge_v(part = "header") %>% 
  valign(valign = "bottom", part = "header") %>% 
  align(align = "center", part = "all") %>% 
  fix_border_issues()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, wasn't aware of fix_border_issues. Thanks!